# change a button call load options in html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a nav bar that I want to call either one of 2 options when clicked according to screen size.

I have tried various options including media queries and javascript but I think my construction of the queries is letting me down.

I need to do this:

````
if screen size <960 then

   <li><a href="page/index.php?lang=en&id_item=2&num_months=2">Page</a></li>
else
   <li><a href="page/index.php?lang=en&id_item=2&num_months=5">Page</a></li>
end```

is there a way to do this?
thank you
````

Comment: You can use css media queries to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the other commenter said, you can use media queries for this. One very easy to understand solution would look like this:

## Solution A: Media Queries

```html
<html>
    <style>
        /* We are disabling linkA from being displayed and allowing linkB to be displayed normally */
        #linkA {
            display: none;
        }

        #linkB {
            display: inherit;
        }

        /* if screen width <= 960px, we will display linkA and hide linkB */
        @media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
            #linkA {
                display: inherit;
            }

            #linkB {
                display: none;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <!-- Notice the ID tags -->
            <li id="linkA"><a href="page/index.php?lang=en&id_item=2&num_months=2">Page</a></li>
            <li id="linkB"><a href="page/index.php?lang=en&id_item=2&num_months=5">Page</a></li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

The media query redefines CSS attributes if the query matches. In your case if the screen width is less or equal 960px.

## Solution B: Javascript

Another solution for your problem would be to call a javascript function when the link is clicked like this:

```html
<span onclick="buildLink()">Page</span>
```

> Note: I did replace `a` with `span` since if there is no `href` there is no reason to use `a`

In the javascript you could dynamically change `num_months` by dividing the width with by the amount of pixels you need to display a month:

```js
function buildLink() {
  const link = "page/index.php?lang=en&id_item=2&num_months=";

  // casting to integer is very important, since we get decimal values otherwise
  const num_months = parseInt(window.innerWidth / 480)

  // window.location.href basically sets the address bar of the browser
  window.location.href = link + num_months
}
```

I hope I have given you a clear answer on your question and some room to think about other possible solutions.

Also: You seem to be new to web development so welcome onboard and enjoy the bumpy ride :)

Comment: thank you for the great explanation and coded examples. The CSS solution works a treat when the browser is being resized on the fly. The Javascript example is also great, the fact it calculates the "NumMonths" and can call the number for the size of layout is very clever. I am going with the CSS version for now but have to work out why the code displays both options in my menu, I think it is some CSS over riding it. Tried using inspect in the browser but it isnt much help - anyone on with the debugginig - again appreciate the response :)